# Qual é a diferença entre angular.extend e angular.merge?

Tags: angularjs

No angular, para estender um objeto, costumo usar `angular.exted

```
var obj = {nome: "wallace"}
angular.extend(obj, {idade: 26})
```

Resultado:

```
Object {nome: "wallace", idade: 26}
```

Porém, percebi que, ao usar `angular.merge`, o resultado é o mesmo:

```
angular.merge(obj, {idade: 26})
```

Resultado:

```
Object {nome: "wallace", idade: 26}
```

Qual é a diferença entre ambos?

Comment: http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/copy-vs-extend-vs-merge/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As duas funções fazem a mesma coisa com uma sútil diferença. Ambas copiam as propriedades de um ou mais objetos fontes para um objeto destino.

## A diferença

#### [angular.merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)

Faz uma cópia "profunda" (cópia recursiva) das propriedades, ou seja, propriedades que são objetos serão re-criadas de forma que não apontem para as mesmas referências da(s) base(s).

#### [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

Faz uma cópia simples (ou rasa) das propriedades, ou seja, as propriedades que são objetos apontarão para a mesma referência da(s) base(s).

### Exemplo:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('mainController', mainControllerFn);

function mainControllerFn(){
  /* ***** merge ***** */
  
  var mPessoa1 = { nome: 'Joaquim', email: 'joaquim@jmail.com' };
  var mPessoa2 = { sobrenome: 'Soares', usuario: {username: 'joaquim1', isAdmin: false } };
  
  angular.merge(mPessoa1, mPessoa2);
  
  console.log(mPessoa1);
  console.log(mPessoa1.usuario === mPessoa2.usuario); 
  // mPessoa1.usuario e mPessoa2.usuario não apontam para a mesma referência
  
  /* ***** extend ***** */
  
  var ePessoa1 = { nome: 'Joaquim', email: 'joaquim@jmail.com' };
  var ePessoa2 = { sobrenome: 'Soares', usuario: {username: 'joaquim1', isAdmin: false } };
  
  angular.extend(ePessoa1, ePessoa2);
  
  console.log(ePessoa1);
  console.log(ePessoa1.usuario === ePessoa2.usuario); 
  // ePessoa1.usuario e ePessoa2.usuario apontam para a mesma referência
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, então é muito sério a escolha de qual usar. O framework que eu uso trabalha relacionamentos como "subobjetos" (objetos dentro do outro). Então em alguns casos, vai ser preferível usar `merge`, para não ter problema com referências de objetos.

Answer (score 3):

**Extend**:

> `angular.extend(dst, src1, src2, ...)` is to shallow copy the properties
>   of the source objects from right to left, all the way to the
>   destination object.

Traduzindo: `angular.extend(dst, src1, src2, ...)`  é a cópia simples das propriedades dos objetos de origem da direita para a esquerda, todo o caminho para o objeto de destino.

```
var src1 = { name: 'David', age: 30 }; // source 1
var src2 = { age: 26, skill: {} }; // source 2
var dst = {}; // destination

console.log(angular.extend(dst, src1, src2));
// Output: { name: 'David', age: 26, skill: {} }

console.log(src2.skill === dst.skill);
// Output: true
// src2 and dst share the same skill object due to shallow copy.
```

**Merge**:

> `angular.merge` is an Angular 1.4+ API that is to deep (recursively)
>   copy the properties of the source objects to the destination object.

Traduzindo: `angular.merge` é profunda (de forma recursiva), copia as propriedades dos objetos de origem para o objeto de destino.

Aqui usamos mesmo exemplo substituindo `angular.extend` por `angular.merge`:

```
var src1 = { name: 'David', age: 30 };
var src2 = { age: 26, skill: {} };
var dst = {};

console.log(angular.merge(dst, src1, src2));
// Output: { name: 'David', age: 26, skill: {} }
// It seems to the same result as the previous example's, however, ...

console.log(src2.skill === dst.skill);
// Output: false
// src2.skill and dst.skill point to different skill objects due to deep copy.
```

Referência: [Copy vs. Extend vs. Merge](http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/copy-vs-extend-vs-merge/)